# Feynman-Kac for heat equation on a compact manifold with boundary

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, heat-equation

It is known that for any open $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, given $f \in L^2(\Omega)$, $x \in \Omega$, one has
$$e^{t\Delta}f(x) = \mathbb{E}_x(f(\omega(t))\psi_\Omega(\omega, t)), $$
where $\Delta $ is the Dirichlet Laplacian, and $\psi_\Omega(\omega, t) = 1, \text{ if } \omega([0, t]) \subset \Omega$, and $0$ otherwise. For a reference, see Taylor's PDE book, Vol II, Chapter 11.

My question is, will the same statement hold if $\Omega \subset M$, where $M$ is a compact Riemannian manifold? The only reference I know which constructs Wiener measures on Riemannian manifolds is the following [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.5082) of Baer and Pfaeffle, but they do not discuss the Dirichlet problem explicitly. This is mainly a reference request.